# Reactive Stream skip filter on certain Exception

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Say I have a reactive stream like so:

```java
Flux<App> apps = this.getApps(arg)
     .filter( res -> firstFilter())
     .filter( res -> secondFilter())
```

And say that the `getApps()` call returns `UnsupportedOperationException`. How could one skip the `firstFilter` and return a default vault for the `secondFilter` when this exception is raised without resolving the whole chain?

Note that `UnsupportedOperationException` should be the only exception that results in the `firstFilter` being skipped.

For example one can use `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResume` for a fallback, but they would complete the whole chain, and only `onErrorResume` could discriminate between exception types.

Comment: so you mean you want when getApps() throws an exception to continue with a custom set stream that you want to provide to second filter?

Comment: makes more sense when 1st filter throws exception but I have not understood

Comment: Yep! Say that getApps() returns that specific exception, I'd 'like to have error handling logic that can skip the firstFilter if that exception is raised and provide a default value for the rest of the chain

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Stream<> stream = null; //your type here
try{    
  stream = this.getApps(arg).filter( res -> firstFilter());
}catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
  stream = Stream.of("1","2","3"); // you default provided stream of strings for example
}finally {
  stream.filter( res -> secondFilter())
}
```

Comment: Would this work if getApps() returns a mono stream? Since would the exception get raised immediately?

Comment: @Chaos if getApps() returns a stream it would be passed on 1stFilter first and then on 2ndFilter

Comment: Well I feel dumb not sure why I didn't think of it this simply! Was just trying to solve it with streams.